# How to enable rubocop rails cops automatically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubocop

Is there a way to always enable rubocop rails cops via the config? I know I can run them via `-R`, but I'd like to make sure, that they are run when I just call `rubocop` alone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Things have changed a bit since the last answer:

Rubocop team wanted to separate rails from the core of rubocop (which I think is great).
See [this issue](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop/issues/5976) and [this PR](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop/pull/7095) for more information.

So the new way of using Rails cops in Rubocop is by installing [ruboco-rails](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop-rails) gem.
Then in `.rubocop.yml` simply add:

```
require: rubocop-rails
```

Details [here](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop-rails#rubocop-configuration-file).

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

As a minor follow-up point to Francois's note, if you want to enable multiple external cops, do it like this:

Some of the docs for other rubocop libraries show this in the installation docs and others don't. Felt appropriate to add on as I found this while searching around for the proper syntax

```
require:
  - rubocop-rspec
  - rubocop-rails
```